# Pagination in Codeigniter giving the error Invalid arguments for foreach()

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to add pagination to my Codeigniter project but every time i get the error that Invalid arguments supplied for foreach(). Could someone help me please.
The code in the Controller

```
        public function staff()
{
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $config['base_url'] = 'staff';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->staff_model->record_count();
    $config['per_page'] = 4;
    $config['num_links'] = 2;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

    $data['data'] = $this->staff_model->get_staff($config["per_page"], $page);

    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->load->view('templates/header',$data);
    $this->load->view('pages/staff',$data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    $this->load->helper('url');

}
```

The Code in my view

```
     foreach ($staff as $staff_item){ ?>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 animate-box text-center">
                <div class="doctor border border-secondary" style="background-color: white; border-style: solid; height: 450px;">

<a href="<?php echo site_url('welcome/viewstaff/'.$staff_item['slug']); ?>"> <img src="<?php echo base_url().'uploads/'.$staff_item['pic_file'] ?>" class="img-fluid" style="width: 253px; height: 250px"></a>
                        <div class="desc">
<h3 ><a href="<?php echo site_url('welcome/viewstaff/'.$staff_item['slug']); ?> " style="color: green"><?php echo $staff_item['title']; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $staff_item['name']; ?></a>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-external-link" aria-hidden="true"></i></h3>
                        <p ><?php echo $staff_item['department']; ?></p>
                        <h3><?php echo $staff_item['designation']; ?></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: check the variable $staff is defined or not. I think you should use $data in place of $staff in foreach().

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
public function staff()
{
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $config['base_url'] = 'staff';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->staff_model->record_count();
    $config['per_page'] = 4;
    $config['num_links'] = 2;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

    //here I changed data with staff 
    $data['staff'] = $this->staff_model->get_staff($config["per_page"], $page); 

    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->load->view('templates/header',$data);
    $this->load->view('pages/staff',$data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    $this->load->helper('url');

}
```

Comment: Still getting the same kind of error. I strongly suspect that the problem is how i've structured foreach() in the view .